# Is there another way of ignoring values using a while(true) loop besides using 'continue'?

Tags: java, overriding, continue, suppress

I've been asked to get user input and ignore values that don't fall within the range of -30 and 40. To skip over invalid numbers I use a 'continue' statement. I've googled sources saying continue / break are bad practice. The IDE is also throwing an "unnecessary continue" warning. Is the code below good practice in solving this problem, should I just override the warning or address it?

My code is as shown below:

```
public class Temperatures 
{

@SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryContinue")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Write your code here. 
    while(true)
    {
        //ask user for input
        double userInput = Double.parseDouble(reader.nextLine());

        //makes sure temperature is within range, if it isn't ignores value and moves on
        if (userInput < -30.0 || userInput > 40.0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        //adds value to graph
        else
        {
            Graph.addNumber(userInput);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Inverse the `if` statement so that it only adds values when they are within the acceptable range...

Comment: ahh you're right that was really dumb of me, thanks!

Comment: The reason for the warning was the `else`. If you'd removed that the warning would have gone too.

Comment: `continue` will skip over the rest of the loop to the end of the loop body, and then repeat the loop.  But there's nothing to skip.  The program wasn't going to execute the `else` branch anyway, and there's nothing else to skip over.  You could just delete that line (making the `if` part an empty `{ }`) and the program would work exactly the same.  But inverting the `if` statement is better.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the IDE is showing the warning because if you removed the continue your code would work exactly the same.  Think about it.

Answer (score 2):

> The IDE is also throwing an "unnecessary continue" warning.

It is an unnecessary `continue`. Why?

If your `if` statement turns true, `else` would not be executed. If the `if` condition is false, `else` would be executed. Hence, there is no need of a `continue` here.

`continue` should have been used if:

```
while(true)
    {
        double userInput = Double.parseDouble(reader.nextLine());
        if (userInput < -30.0 || userInput > 40.0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        Graph.addNumber(userInput);
     }
```

There is no `else` statement, hence now you have to use a `continue` to skip  the further execution of the current iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use continue in your case. Use this instead:

```
if( userInput >= -30 && userInput <= 40){
    Graph.addNumber(userInput);
}
```